# How to monitor Cardano Minswap transactions using Blockfrost?

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction, cardano-db-sync, blockfrost

I was trying to monitor the swap actions

like who swapped which A to B Token, as real-time from Minswap platform.

I was using Blockfrost webhook for this, but I fetched lots of transactions including those (main swap transaction which are what I want).

The problem is that I couldn't filter them out of all transactions.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you able to resolved your issues?

Comment: Oh, @Hebrew, I solved this issue.

Comment: I used a blockfrost api for this issue.
To be exact, blockfrost supports webhooks features which can be used as a hook to catch up certain cardano transactions.
So you can monitor Minswap Transactions (You know Minswap Order, Pool contract address).

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the [blockfrost-adapter](https://github.com/minswap/blockfrost-adapter) from MinSwap.